# Sourdough bread keeps cracking underneath. What could be the reason?

Tags: bread

[image: sourdough bread cracks]

We have been facing this problem as you can see in the image. This dough is 75% hydrated and it is always cooked in a ventilated oven over a baking stone, the temperature of baking is 220° Celsius / 428° Fahrenheit, while it bakes we create steam inside the oven by sprinkling water inside it. 
In the beginning of the baking process the oven spring happens accordingly, after a while the oven spring stops upwards and the bread beggins to crack underneath, creating in some cases huge cracks. What can we do to prevent it? What could we having being doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Another picture, with a better view of the damage to the bottom, might help us answer. If you don't have enough rep to add another picture, just post a URL and someone will be by to edit it into your question.

Comment: I voted to close, then retracted because I linked it to the incorrect former question.  It looks like I can't vote again.  However I believe you can find your answer by typing 56221 (the reference to the prior question) in the search bar.  Someone with more power than I can help sort this out, I suppose.

Comment: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56221/bread-doesnt-split-at-the-score

Answer (score 1):

Cracks around the bottom are said to be caused by cold baking sheets. Something about the temperature gradient needs to change. Try baking on a preheated pizza stone.